# Mocking a specific class object stubs failed tests mockito

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm reading in a json object that is populating my class object so I am mocking my class object and not sure which way is the best way to do that.  Here's my method:

```
    public List<Person> readFile(String filename) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    int count = 0;

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
               filename));

       JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
       JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("people");
        //System.out.println("Debug: " + array.size());
        if(array != null) {
            while (count < array.size()) {
                Person person = new Person();
                JSONObject people = (JSONObject) array.get(count);
                person.setName((String) people.get("name"));
                Long age = (Long) people.get("age");
                person.setAge(Integer.valueOf(age.intValue()));
                person.setSex((String) people.get("sex"));
                person.setIllness((String) people.get("illness"));
                list.add(person);
                count++;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

This takes a filename and returns a list, in this case, a specific file object list.   Here's my test so far:

```
package pricing;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.pricing.DiscountPricing;
import com.pricing.model.Person;

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DiscountPricingTest {

private static DiscountPricing mockDPclass;
private static Person mockPerson1;
private static Person mockPerson2;
private static Person mockPerson3;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    mockDPclass = mock(DiscountPricing.class);
    mockPerson1 = new Person(50, "Allergies", "Kelly", "female");
    mockPerson2 = new Person(40, "Sleep Apnea", "Josh", "male");
    mockPerson3 = new Person(20, "Heart Disease", "Brad", "male");
}

@Test
public void readFileTest() {
    String filename = "Consumers.json";
    DiscountPricing dpclass = new DiscountPricing();
    List<Person> allPeople = dpclass.readFile(filename);
    List<Person> mockPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
    mockPeople.add(mockPerson1);
    mockPeople.add(mockPerson2);
    mockPeople.add(mockPerson3);
    assertEquals(mockPeople.size(), allPeople.size());
    assertTrue(allPeople.get(0).getName().equals("Kelly"));
}
}
```

Seeing if my use of mocking is correct with Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mocked the class you want to test. i.e.: `mockedYourClass = mock(YourClass.class);`. You should do this in the setUp() method in your test class.

Further you are not stubbing the methods of your mocked class with mocked data before testing, i.e.:
`when(mockDPclass.readFile("Consumers.json")).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(mockPerson1, mockPerson2, mockPerson3));` You should put this in the end of your setUp() method.

In your readFileTest() method you can then do something like:

```
List<Person> persons = mockDPclass.readFile("Consumers.json");
assertEquals(3, persons.size());
Person person = persons.get(0);
assertEquals("Kelly", person.getName());
```

Here is a nice tutorial how to get started with mocking in java: https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-mocking-java

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the reason to mock objects is because they are required dependencies for the thing you are trying to test and mocking them out simplifies making real objects and give you a way to control expectations and check interactions.

In your case, you are testing a function to verify that it reads data from a file correctly. Your dependencies are:

- The file name you're reading from
- The `JSONParser` instance you `new` in the method to do that parsing
- The `FileReader` instance you `new` in the method to read the file

Given this there are two things you can do:

1) Create fake files with test data that you test against. Then your test would look something like this.

```
@Test
public void readFileTest() {
    DiscountPricing dp = new DiscountPricing();
    List<Person> emptyList = dp.readFile("test_file_empty.json");
    assertThat(emptyList, is(empty()));

    List<Person> singleItemList = dp.readFile("test_file_single.json");
    assertThat(singleItemList, hasSize(1));
    // TODO: Assert state of Person at singleItemList(0) is correct

    List<Person> multiItemList = dp.readFile("test_file_multi.json");
    assertThat(mutilItemList, hasSize(2));
    // TODO: Assert state of each person in list is correct
}
```

2) Allow *injecting* the `JSONParser` you need so you can mock it and provide dummy data to test against.

```
@Test
public void readFileTest() {
    JSONParser mockParser = mock(JSONParser.class);
    DiscountPricing dp = new DiscountPricing();
    dp.setJSONParser(mockParser); // Parser is now a field in DiscountPricing you use in the readFile method

    JSONObject emptyObject = new JSONObject();
    when(mockParser.parse(any(FileReader.class))).thenReturn(emptyObject);
    List<Person> emptyList = dp.readFile("this doesn't matter");
    assertThat(emptyList, is(empty()));

    JSONObject singleObject = new JSONObject();
    // TODO: Populate singleObject with fake fields
    when(mockParser.parse(any(FileReader.class))).thenReturn(singleObject);
    List<Person> singleItemList = dp.readFile("this doesn't matter");
    assertThat(singleItemList, hasSize(1));
    // TODO: Assert state of Person at singleItemList(0) is correct

    JSONObject multiObject = new JSONObject();
    // TODO: Populate multiObject with fake fields
    when(mockParser.parse(any(FileReader.class))).thenReturn(multiObject);
    List<Person> multiItemList = dp.readFile("this doesn't matter");
    assertThat(mutilItemList, hasSize(2));
    // TODO: Assert state of each person in list is correct
}
```

With option `1` you are testing against real data, it's a more realistic test of your code, and it's easier to set up - but you have the data in a separate file so it's removed from your test.

With option `2` you test case is clearly laid out in code making it easer to read and update, but it's a bit more verbose since you have to fake out all the sample data in code.

Which option you go with depends mostly on style and what works for you, but I'd probably favor option `1`, personally.

Hope that helps!